# django отображение название моделей

Tags: python, django

Вопрос глупый но всё же , хочу спросить.

В чем разница отображения в стринге  в моделях

```
class Simple(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True)
```

Вариант 1

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.name)
```

Вариант 2

```
def __str__(self)
    return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разницы никакой - результат будет один. Это просто разные способы форматирования строк. `format()` был введен на замену `%`, исправляя какие-то его недостатки.

Начиная с Python 3.6 доступен новый метод форматирования - [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
def __str__(self)
    return f'{self.name}'
```